# Problem with docker-compose up on windows 10 home "exec: not found"

Tags: java, mysql, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to create an image of a application that I'm creating from a Udemy course, it is a Java Spring-Boot REST application which uses MySQL database. Here's the problem: I've done the same steps as my teacher show on video, but for some reason, my docker can't run the image.
Here's the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile and the logs:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: raphasalomao/restudemy
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: docker
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
      MYSQL_DATABASE: restudemy
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    networks:
      - udemy-network
  restudemy:
    image: raphasalomao/restudemy
    restart: always
    build: /Users/rapha/OneDrive/Documentos/Projetos/RestUdemy/02 RestWithSpringBoot
    working_dir: /Users/rapha/OneDrive/Documentos/Projetos/RestUdemy/02 RestWithSpringBoot
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      SPRING_BOOT_ENVIRONMENT: Production
    volumes:
      - ./02 RestWithSpringBoot:/Users/rapha/OneDrive/Documentos/Projetos/RestUdemy/02 RestWithSpringBoot
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - udemy-network
networks:
    udemy-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7.23
EXPOSE 3308
```

LOG:

> /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh: 50: exec: mysqld: not found

I've tried to change the $PATH on wsl, use mysqld.exe instead of MySQL, update Windows, install docker and WSL again, but nothing works.

Comment: If that's a Linux-based container then `mysqld.exe` won't be the solution here.

Comment: Why are you building a MySQL container? Just use one of the [official ones](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, actually, this is the first time that I use docker, o don't know much about, but the problem was the mysql image, i change from "image: raphasalomao/restudemy" to "image: mysql:5.7"

Answer (score 0):

This image "raphasalomao/restudemy" came from which Registry? DockerHub??
I Couldnt find this on DockerHub.
But based on the message, it appears to be a Maven related Image.

Why not use [mysql Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)?

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.